Multple files zipped & uploaded at the same time without causing memory overflow
In my app (Laravel + Inertia + Vue3) user selects multiple files using input. I need to compress them into zip and upload to server in chunks for further operations.
I tried using JSZip library, but there's a problem with generateAsync() - when user select big total filesize (for example 500+ files, over 3 gb) then I get error RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed which is caused by the fact that full zip first need to be created in memory and only then it's being uploaded using chunks.
I don't want to send files to server and compress them server-side as the goal is to use minimal bandwith.
So the idea is that the zip file should be generated user-side and uploaded using chunks at the same time without the need to store big zip file in memory. Can anyone suggest how to approach that?
generateNodeStream() from JSZIp is a no go as it's not vastly supported.

The Compression Streams API provides chunk-based encoding with Javascript, and you can control the sizes of chunks and allocated buffers.

That API does not write zip files.

Actually zip is not mandatory - the goal is to use less bandwidth than just uploading raw files user selected, so I guess compressed stream would work too.

How do you control size of chunk in compression stream API though?

It is certainly possible, but you may need to write your own streaming zipper in Javascript. zipflow is an example in C. It uses a small amount of memory to create zip entries and files of arbitrarily large size.

@Mark Adler - Would native Compression Streams suffice instead of writing a custom impl?

@anthumchris No. That API does not write the zip format. The raw deflate capability of that API could be part of a solution, but you would need to roll your own code to write the zip format around the deflate data, as well as to compute the CRC for each entry.
